# Optimal hardware for linear algebra operations

Tags: slam, kalman-filter

I've been working lately on SLAM algorithms implementing extended kalman filtering to brush up on some localisation techniques and I have been thinking forward to the hardware side of things. Are there embedded chips such a microcontroller that are optimised for large linear algebra operations? What sort of embedded options are the best for processing these sorts of operations?

Comment: sounds like an application for an FPGA

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call it an optimal solution but I've been working with some odroid XUs and have been very happy with their behavior. I'm using the Eigen linear algebra library along with ros and opencv.